# Resolve original node by Identifier in TypeScript AST

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm traversing Typescript AST and collecting some data.

And when I encounter a reference to a variable (`Identifier` node) I actually want to get original node (for example `VariableDeclaration`).

How can I resolve it?
Now the only thing I can think of is to traverse AST again from the root and try to find it but it feels hacky...

Does Typescript provide some way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that happens to be very easy task:

```
const originalNode = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(node);
```

and that's it!

In the `originalNode.valueDeclaration` we have now original node.